# Gradle Task Ordering with dependsOn mustRunAfter and doLast

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am working on creating a `.gradle` file to automate a bunch of manual operations during my project build.

I am trying to enforce [task ordering](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks) using `dependsOn`, `mustRunAfter`, and `doLast`. However, I am not getting the desired output.

Here is my .gradle file with some dummy tasks and print statements to show what I have.

```
tasks.register('setupProjectTasks') {
    println 'Debug 1 sPT'
    dependsOn 'task1'
    doLast {
        exec {
            println 'Run shell script'
            commandLine '/path/a.sh'
        }
    }
}

tasks.register('task1') {
    println 'Debug 2 task'
    dependsOn 'someCleanup'
    dependsOn 'depA'
    tasks.findByName('depA').mustRunAfter('someCleanup')
    doLast {
        println 'restart' // Restart tomcat here
    }
}

tasks.register('someCleanup') {
    println 'Debug 3 some cleanup'
    dependsOn 'subTask1'
    dependsOn 'subTask2'
}

tasks.register('depA') {
    println 'depA'
    dependsOn 'subTaskA1'
    dependsOn 'subTaskA2'
    tasks.findByName('subTaskA2').mustRunAfter('subTaskA1')
    doLast {
        println 'depA done'
    }
}

tasks.register('subTask1') {
    println 'subtask 1'
}

tasks.register('subTask2') {
    println 'subtask 2'
}

tasks.register('subTaskA1') {
    println 'subtask A1'
}

tasks.register('subTaskA2') {
    println 'subtask A2'
}
```

This is the task order I wish to achieve.

```
- setupProjectTasks
  - task1 (First 'someCleanup', and then 'depA', and 'restart' at the end
    - someCleanup (the order between subTask1 and subTask2 doesn't matter)
    - depA (below should be executed in the exact order)
      - subTaskA1
      - subTaskA2
      - depA done (print line)
    - restart (print line)
  - Run shell script (print line and run shell script)
```

I always want to run all these tasks in the order specified. I understand how `dependsOn` and `mustRunAfter` works. But I don't seem to have them working the right way for me.

This is the output I get

```
Debug 1 sPT
Debug 2 task
depA
subtask A2
Debug 3 some cleanup
subtask A1
subtask 1
subtask 2

> Task :depA
depA done

> Task :task1
restart

> Task :setupProjectTasks
Run shell script
Hi
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not use `print("...\n")` please, just use println that prints your text and adds `\n` itself

Comment: In what order should the tasks `subtask1` and `subtask2` be arranged?

Comment: Is `restart` a task?

Comment: @MaksimEliseev I also wanted to do a few things that's not just a task. I want to run some `.sh` scripts as part of the config setup. Also restart tomcat. `subtask1` and `subtask2` can be in any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you misunderstood Gradle and its concept of tasks. Because tasks in Gradle cannot have hierarchy. Also you don't have the ability to run tasks inside another tasks. The task in Gradle should do one small or possibly big thing.

Maybe it would be better to use methods instead of tasks.

To order tasks you just need to use `dependsOn`. Here is an example that I created for you to show how could it be - [link](https://github.com/elimxim/so-gradle-dependson).

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a lot! This definitely clarifies a lot for me :)

Comment: I've done some updates: I added `doLast { }` and put `println` inside this clojure to avoid printing before the execution of a task @SyncMaster

Comment: I suppose when I updated my answer (i just changed link to github) your accept have been canceled. Sorry, can you accept my answer again? @SyncMaster